# Efficient scalar map / for idiom in Scala?

Tags: scala, bytecode

What is the most concise and bytecode efficient way to access a scalar expression **multiple times** from deep within another expression?

All of the functions in the following code (exc. **scalar4**) function as desired. But only **bytecoder** emits efficient bytecode (although it ends badly with ISTORE 2 ILOAD 2), the others each generate a half dozen INVOKE's.

This idiom is also handy for passing arbitrary parts of a tuple as parameters:

```
for (a_tuple) { f(_._3, _._1) + g(_._2) }  // caution NOT legal Scala
```

In this example **intro** represents an expensive function that should only be called once.

```
object Hack extends App
{
  @inline final def fur[T, V](x :T)(f :T => V) :V = f(x)

  @inline final def pfor[T, V](x :T)(pf :PartialFunction[T, V]) = pf(x)

  @inline final def cfor[T, V](x :T)(f :T => V) :V = x match { case x => f(x) }

  def intro :Int = 600 // only one chance to make a first impression

  def bytecoder = intro match { case __ => __ + __ / 600 }

  def functional = fur(intro) (x => x + x / 600)

  def partial = pfor(intro) { case __ => __ + __ / 600 }

  def cased = cfor(intro) ($ => $ + $ / 600)

  def optional = Some(intro).map(? => ? + ? / 600).get

  def folder = Some(intro).fold(0)(? => ? + ? / 600)

  // the for I wish for
  def scalar4 = for(intro) (_ + _ / 600) // single underline!

  println(bytecoder, functional, partial, cased, optional, folder)
}
```

public bytecoder()I

```
ALOAD 0
INVOKEVIRTUAL com/_601/hack/Hack$.intro ()I
ISTORE 1
ILOAD 1
ILOAD 1
SIPUSH 600
IDIV
IADD
ISTORE 2
ILOAD 2
IRETURN
```

Comment: `def tempvar = { var x = intro; x + x / 600 }`?  You can put a block anywhere, you know.

Comment: If you're looking for "bytecode efficiency" in Scala, you're in the wrong place.

Comment: Isn't the JIT able to optimize the final useless ISTORE 2 / ILOAD 2?

Comment: @BrunoReis - Certainly, but as it's such a simple optimization I was surprised scalac didn't do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create a local block with a temporary val.  Seriously.  It's compact: just one character longer than "idiomatic" pipe

```
{ val x = whatever; x * x / 600 }
whatever match { case x => x * x / 600 }
whatever |> { x => x * x / 600 }
```

It's efficient: minimum bytecode possible.

```
// def localval = { val x = whatever; x * x / 600 }
public int localval();
  Code:
   0:   aload_0
   1:   invokevirtual   #18; //Method whatever:()I
   4:   istore_1
   5:   iload_1
   6:   iload_1
   7:   imul
   8:   sipush  600
   11:  idiv
   12:  ireturn
```

The only thing it *doesn't* do is act as a postfix operator, and you have `match` for that when you really need that form and can't tolerate extra bytecode.

Comment: **Accepting** because it's bytecode efficient and simple.  But I still don't like the semicolon and having to name the _anonymous_ `val`.  Thanks for your attention to this question.

Answer (score 1):

```
// Canadian scalar "for" expression
@inline final case class four[T](x: T)
{
  @inline def apply(): T = x

  @inline def apply[V](f: Function1[T,          V]): V = f(x)
  @inline def apply[V](f: Function2[T, T,       V]): V = { val $ = x; f($, $) }
  @inline def apply[V](f: Function3[T, T, T,    V]): V = { val $ = x; f($, $, $) }
  @inline def apply[V](f: Function4[T, T, T, T, V]): V = { val $ = x; f($, $, $, $) }
  // ...
}

// Usage
val x = System.currentTimeMillis.toInt % 1 + 600

def a = four(x)() + 1
def b = four(x)(_ + 1)
def c = four(x)(_ + _ / x)
def d = four(x)(_ + _ / _)
def e = four(x)(_ + _ / _ - _) + 600

println(a, b, c, d, e)
```

With this `four(){}`, bytecode and performance is sacrificed in favour of style.

Also, this **dangerously** breaks from tradition, that underlines are used only once per parameter.